what does it mean if Linux thinks my WiFi card is an Ethernet interface?
I have two laptops, both of which are believed to contain a Intel Wireless-AC 9260 2x2 802.11ac + BT5.0 (vPro) WiFi card.
On one laptop, running Ubuntu 22.04, the OS identifies the card as a Wireless interface with wireless capabilities.
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       logical name: wlp59s0
       version: 29
       serial: d4:3b:04:cb:24:92
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.5.0-45-generic firmware=46.fae53a8b.0 9260-th-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.2.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:ed400000-ed403fff

$ sudo lspci -nn
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)

On the other laptop, running Ubuntu 24.04, the OS identifies the card as an Ethernet interface with no wireless capability. Despite this, the WiFi somehow works on the second laptop, albeit with severely degraded performance.
$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Wi-Fi 5(802.11ac) Wireless-AC 9x6x [Thunder Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       logical name: wlp59s0
       version: 29
       serial: 2c:db:07:b9:ab:b8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-39-generic firmware=46.7e3e4b69.0 9260-th-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.2.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       resources: irq:174 memory:ed400000-ed403fff

$ sudo lspci -nn
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 5(802.11ac) Wireless-AC 9x6x [Thunder Peak] [8086:2526] (rev 29)

What does it mean if the second card lacks a wireless entry under capabilities:?
If it is meaningful, why does the WiFi continue to work anyways on the second machine?
Is the lack of wireless capability in the second description responsible for degraded WiFi performance on the second machine?
If so, how do I get the OS to identify the card as a WiFi card?

Does the card work on both systems? Sounds like a difference in lshw, there is probably a way, to reidentify the adapter I just don’t know the command without significant research

Is the lack of wireless capability in the second description responsible for degraded WiFi performance on the second machine? try running Ubuntu 22.04 on the machine ... now test performance ... is it degraded ... if not, the issue is likely Ubuntu 24.04 specific

Sounds like a driver thing to me.  A WIFI card presents and behaves very similarly to an Ethernet card, save for the addition of the logic used to secureishly  chuck the data into the air and pull it out.
